# xticklabels for sorted data

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I am trying to sort data from a file then plot it.  This code seems to
do that.

```
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
name,b
sue,5
jean,3
jim,4
\end{filecontents*}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data.dat}{\datatable}
\pgfplotstablesort[sort key={b}]{\sorted}{\datatable}
\pgfplotstableset{
    create on use/rank/.style=
        {create col/set list={1,2,3}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot+ [only marks] table [x=rank,y=b] {\sorted};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I want to use labels (names) from the 'name' column in the sorted data as
xticklabels.  This is as close as I can get:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
name,b
sue,5
jean,3
jim,4
\end{filecontents*}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data.dat}{\datatable}
\pgfplotstablesort[sort key={b}]{\sorted}{\datatable}
\pgfplotstableset{
    create on use/rank/.style=
        {create col/set list={1,2,3}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xticklabels from table={\sorted}{name}]
    \addplot+ [only marks] table [x=rank,y=b] {\sorted};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

There are obvious problems from arising from my deficient code. How
can I get all names to appear as xticklabels, and to follow the order
in the sorted data?

Comment: Simply add `xtick=data` to the `axis` options ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already stated in the [comments below the question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/439011/xticklabels-for-sorted-data#comment1102375_439011) you simply need to add `xtick=data` to achieve what you want.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
    \begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
        name,b
        sue,5
        jean,3
        jim,4
    \end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data.dat}{\datatable}
    \pgfplotstablesort[sort key={b}]{\sorted}{\datatable}
    \pgfplotstableset{
        create on use/rank/.style={
            create col/set list={1,2,3},
        },
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        % add `xtick=data' to show only ticks where data points of the
        % *first* `\addplot' command (only) exist
        xtick=data,
        xticklabels from table={\sorted}{name},
        % (add this so the labels have the same baseline)
        typeset ticklabels with strut,
    ]
        \addplot+ [only marks] table [x=rank,y=b] {\sorted};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]